# Is it possible to share and see a link using ShareKit in iOS(need the exact way as Web)

Tags: iphone, ipad, facebook, sharekit

I have an app and I am using ShareKit for sharing in Facebook. I am able to share URLs, images and texts to FB using that. But why did the link/url share do not work the same way as when I share a url from Web Facebook. I have got many contents like image in my url and while doing the Share through web I am able to see the image and a small portion of content, but while I am doing it from iPhone using ShareKit, it just gives the heading/title and we need to click on that link(no images or contents).

If anyone know the solution, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you share a link on the Facebook site it will automatically fetch the URL and display some appropriate images that you can choose from. However, when directly interacting with the API this won't happen. You must provide the image yourself (or Facebook may use the image associated with your application). ShareKit may abstract this away from you, so you might want to look into using the Facebook SDK and Graph APIs directly.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Instead of posting(POST) the attachment dialog, just use GET method in the load function and pass the link you want to share. :)